# PHP complex check between different arrays

Tags: php

My goal is to decide if the
`$iCurrentMembershipId` can access the 
`$aCurrentMenu`  array
based on: if the 
`$iCurrentMembershipId` is in the 
`$aRescrictAccess` array.

```
if(is_array($aRescrictAccess)){
   // Not sure what to do
}
```

Ultimately, I would need deny access to the page if the users `$iCurrentMembershipId` is in the `$aRescrictAccess` array.

Comment: How are the `$aRescrictAccess` array and the `$aCurrentMenu` array structured ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($aRestrictAccess)){
    if(in_array($iCurrentMembershipId, $aRestricAccess) === FALSE){
        /* display $aCurrentMenu */
    }
}
```